# Find Azure ResourceGroup from Azure SQL Server Name

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to write a powershell script that deploys a BACPAC to an Azure database. I found this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-import-from-bacpac-powershell) on the Microsoft site

I don't have to have to ask which resource group the SQL Server is in so using Powershell, is it possible to find the resource group a SQL server resides in if you only know the server name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$resourceGroupName = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Get-AzureRmSqlServer | where {$_.ServerName -eq 'Your Server Name Here'}).ResourceGroupName
```

Comment: Didn't think you'd be able to have duplicate server names but will watch out for that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah, you are correct about the duplicate names not being possible for Azure SQL.  I must have been thinking of other resource types where names are unique per region or subscription.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way of doing this is to use the [Find-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/find-azurermresource?view=azurermps-4.1.0) cmdlet.  You can specify as much information as you'd like (resource group, like name, resource type) to narrow down the search results.

Answer (score 1):

Not really any better or worse than Dean's but using the generic cmdlets (would work for any resourceType):

```
(Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases" -and $_.ResourceName -eq "$svr/$db"}).ResourceGroupName
```

Comment: Why would you use the Get vs Find?  Seems inefficient for subscriptions with many resources deployed.

Comment: Not really any better or worse - one does processing client side (Get), one on the server (Find)...